# Number of combinations $\{a,b,c\}$ from $\{1,2,...,9\}$ such that $a+b+c$ is a multiple of $3$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> **Question**
>
> Find the number of combinations $\{a,b,c\}$, where $a,b,c\in\{1,2,...,9\}$ and $a,b,c$ are distinct, such that $a+b+c$ is a multiple of $3$.

The answer is $30$. My solution is given as follows.

> **Solution**
>
> Case 1: $a\in\{1,4,7\}$ and $b\in\{2,5,8\}$ and $c\in\{3,6,9\}$.
>
> $\text{Number of combinations for Case 1}=3\times 3\times 3=27$
>
> Case 2: $\{a,b,c\}=\{1,4,7\}$ or $\{a,b,c\}=\{2,5,8\}$ or $\{a,b,c\}=\{3,6,9\}$.
>
> $\text{Number of combinations for Case 2}=1+1+1=3$
>
> In total,
>
> $\text{Required number of combinations}=27+3=30$

On the other hands, there is an alternative solution which I cannot see how it works.

> **Alternative Solution**
>
> $\text{Required number of combinations}=1+3+7+8+7+3+1=30$

Can anyone figure out the rationale behind the alternative solution and explain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible sums that are multiples of $3$ are $\{6,9,12,15,18,21,24\}$ and the numbers of combinations that give these sums are those given in the alternative solution.